# Execute multiple command prompt commands in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I need to created a .bat file which does the following things :

1. Go to a folder which is found on Desktop, say "Test"
2. Delete all files which is found in that folder, without asking for confirmation
3. Open the folder "Test" after deletion.

All the commands should be each line for every step mentionned above.

I have tried the following code, but it is not what i'm expecting to do. Steps 1 and 2 is correct, but the folder is not opened.

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd Test && del * /Q && ."
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to open programs/files/folders. To open the current folder in explorer use `start .`, not `.`. So the final result will be

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd Test && del * /Q && start ."
```

Comment: @aschipfl it's necessary. Typing the folder name or `.` in the command line will result in `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @aschipfl it depends. If you want to open in a new instance of cmd then it's necessary